# Como bloquear a minimização e fechamento de um app?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicativo em java, Android Studio, que servirá como cardápio, em tablets. Gostaria de bloquear a minimização e fechamento do mesmo(acredito que o dono do estabelecimento não queira que o cliente utilize o tablet de cardapio para outras funções).

Eu utilizei algumas flags para esconder a barra inferior...com intuito de que o usuário tenha dificuldade em minimizar.

```
View mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
                mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                );
```

Mas ainda assim, se ele buscar a barra ela aparece.
Gostaria de travar a aplicação na tela.
Há como fazer isso?

Comment: Acredito que por questão de segurança, não tenha como fazer com que o sistema operacional apenas exiba o seu aplicativo. O que você pode fazer é tentar dificultar ao máximo para o usuário fechar seu aplicativo configurando onBackPressed() para que quando pressionado, volte para o menu inicial. Agora se o usuário pressionar o botão menu ai já era....

Comment: [Habilitando tela cheia no Android](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

Comment: Simples, você precisa definir seu app pra ser uma laucher.

Assim ele será parte da tela inicial e seus usuarios nunca conseguirá sair dele a não ser que você queira.
Uma maneira simples é usar a intent filter na tela inicial:
'<intent-filter>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" /> 
</intent-filter>'

É totalmente possivel tem vários sistemas funcionando dessa forma.

Comment: @WelbertMoreira sim, vi alguns exemplos de sistemas que rodam dessa maneira...só colocando esse pedaço de código no manifest o app já começa a ter esse comportamento?

Comment: Coloca esse intent filter dentro da activity principal no Manifest